# Finding an element with no tag using XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to locate the first row of text under an H4 element using Selenium.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="login_credentials" class="login_credentials">
    <h4>Accepted usernames are:</h4>
    standard_user<br>
    locked_out_user<br>
    problem_user<br>
    performance_glitch_user<br>
</div>
```

I've tried to access the H4 element and then its children using the path `//h4/text()` but I'm having no luck.

Comment: "*I've tried to access the H4 element and then its children*" -- please post this code

Comment: What do you mean by "under"? What are you trying to locate?

Comment: The H4 is 'Accepted Usernames'

I'm trying to locate the first row of text under that header.

Answer (score 0):

The text is not child of the `<h4>` tag, it is part of the `<div>` element. You can get the text of that element and split by new line `\n` to get the text as array

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_credentials"));
string[] rows = element.Text.Split('\n');
//rows[0] is "Accepted usernames are:"
//rows[1] is "standard_user"
```

As a side note, xpath `text()` returns text node which is not supported by Selenium.